# Unable to login as normal user, after changing user details as admin user

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux, jwt

I logged in as an admin user and updated one of the users' info.  However, after logging out, if I try to log in with that same user, whose info I changed, it says invalid email/password. I changed only the user's name, not their email or password.

The above case is also applicable, in case an admin changes their own details.

All the other users, whose info I didn't edit, are able to log in.

I'm using bcryptjs for one way encryption and jwt for session management and redux for state management.

**UserAction.js**

```
export const updateUser = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) =>
{
try {
dispatch({
  type: USER_UPDATE_REQUEST,
});

const {
  userLogin: { userInfo },
} = getState();

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
  },
};

const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/${user._id}`, user, config);
dispatch({
  type: USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
});
dispatch({
  type: USER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  payload: data,
});
dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_RESET });
} catch (error) {
const message =
  error.response && error.response.data.message
    ? error.response.data.message
    : error.message;
if (message === "Not authorized, token failed") {
  dispatch(logout());
}
dispatch({
  type: USER_UPDATE_FAIL,
  payload: message,
});
}
};
```

**UserReducer.js**

```
export const userDeleteReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case USER_DELETE_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true };
case USER_DELETE_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, success: true };
case USER_DELETE_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
default:
  return state;
  }
  };

 export const userUpdateReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
case USER_UPDATE_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true };
case USER_UPDATE_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, success: true };
case USER_UPDATE_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
case USER_UPDATE_RESET:
  return { user: {} };
default:
  return state;
}
};
```

**UserEditScreen.js**

```
const UserEditScreen = ({ match, history }) => {
 const [name, setName] = useState("");
   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
 const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

 const userId = match.params.id;

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails);
  const { loading, user, error } = userDetails;

  const userUpdate = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdate);
  const {
loading: loadingUpdate,
error: errorUpdate,
success: successUpdate,
 } = userUpdate;

 useEffect(() => {
if (successUpdate) {
  dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATE_RESET });

  history.push("/admin/userlist");
}

if (!user.name || user._id !== userId) {
  dispatch(getUserDetails(userId));
} else {
  setName(user.name);
  setEmail(user.email);
  setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin);
 }
 }, [dispatch, history, user, userId, successUpdate]);

const submitHandler = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
dispatch(
  updateUser({
    _id: userId,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  })
);
};

 return (
   <>
  <Link to="/admin/userList" className="btn btn-light my-3">
    Go Back
  </Link>
  <FormContainer>
    <h1>Edit User</h1>
    {loadingUpdate && <Loader />}
    {errorUpdate && <Message variant="danger">{errorUpdate}</Message>}
    {loading ? (
      <Loader />
    ) : error ? (
      <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
    ) : (
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="isadmin">
          <Form.Check
            type="checkbox"
            label="Is Admin"
            checked={isAdmin === "true"}
            onChange={(e) => setIsAdmin(e.target.checked)}
          ></Form.Check>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
          SAVE
        </Button>
      </Form>
    )}
  </FormContainer>
  </>
 );
 };

export default UserEditScreen;
```